NATS feed caching of fetch N or N-10 messages
We want to improve our user/community feed system with some caching and are considering 2 options:

Cache latest 30 items in NATS KV as feed.0, latest 31-60 in feed.1 . This means updating feed.N on each feed item edit/delete etc.

Push all feed items to feed.itemId as regular messages and fetch latest 30 messages with pull push fetch() function? Is this fast enough? This does not allow paging/offset right?


Which if these 2 is the more go-to solution?
If some one knows any other caching solution which can be solved using NATS please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

fyi people are also excited about per key TTL feature which is coming in server 2.11

The KV (Key-Value) is a cache implemented on top of JetStream. The implementation is similar to how you have described in option 2, except that there are features built into the NATS server specifically to support KV to make it robust and performant, that the client's implementation that is aware of these features.
Have a look at the Key Value Intro examples at Nats By Example.
